# Table view function for select row

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am new for iPhone development. I want to make table view in which i have shown list of categories. When user select on any row then appear a right sign or UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark. And the text of that row save in a string.
How do that in table view? Which method or function used?

Comment: Please read the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure a table view, you give it a delegate that implements the [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) protocol. One of the many messages sent to the delegate is [-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a). As the creator of the delegate, you can implement this method to take whatever action you like when the user selects a row in the table.